# Why doesn't my own GitHub page show my project?

Tags: github, github-pages

This is my first GitHub page; I have created repository and even pasted my project into it, but when I enter the URL it gives me 404 error with "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here" description.
My project called **'weather-app'** and the URL: https://salehghari.github.io/

So it should be like this: https://salehghari.github.io/weather-app/weatherapp.html

Comment: I don't see a `salehghari.github.io` repository, nor does it look like there's a github.io release in https://github.com/salehghari/weather_app. Have you done the basic setup for activating GH pages? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Using_Github_pages

Comment: @ggorlen should my repo be public? Because it is private right now

Comment: Oh, I see the difference between the `-` and the `_`. No, you can [use a private repo in a pro account](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages) but it's sort of hard to help without knowing what state it's in or any information at all besides the public link. Can you share the exact steps you took so others can reproduce the problem? If there's sensitive information in the repo, I'd make a simpler version that reproduces the problem and can be made public.

Comment: @ggorlen I turned it into public now. it is https://github.com/salehghari/salehghari.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your repository on [Github](https://github.com/salehghari/salehghari.github.io) and all the **Builds** under **Actions** are marked as **Failure** with the following error under **Deploy**:

> Error: No uploaded artifact was found!

Under **Build** I see this:

> Error: fatal: No url found for submodule path 'weather-app' in
> .gitmodules Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code
> 128

You are using a **submodule** but I don't see a clickable link on the repository, are you sure that is correct ? Check if this **submodule** is correct, there is also an issue on [Github Community](https://github.community/t/failed-to-publish-static-site-spa-with-submodules/219880/2) about this topic.

Comment: yes it isn't clickable, I don't know what is wrong with it. should I delete this repo and make another?

Comment: @saleh probably with the first configuration you didn't set up correctly the theme using the submodule. I used Jekyll in the past and I followed the [Setup page](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/) on the documentation. Besides the submodule and theme, I don't see any HTML file. After you apply the theme and you create some content everything will be applied automatically. I don't think it's necessary to delete the repository but it's better to remove the submodule. You don't need it to apply a theme

Comment: yeah that submodule caused the problem, I have deleted it and created new one so it doesn't have a submodule and it works! anyway thank you for your helps :D <3

Comment: I'm glad that worked, could you mark my answer as acceptable ? Other users might had the same issue with their repository and it could be helpful to them :)

Comment: of course! Sorry I forgot

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the branch you want to use for your GitHub pages site.

[These are the steps you need to follow](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: github-pages failed

Answer (score 0):

I deleted that repo and created another. **that un-clickable folder in previous repo was caused the 404 error**. Because I had pushed that folder on GitHub once so it means It had had a **.git** file in it. Thank you every one I appreciate your helps